# Link in the question status block leads to the wrong site

Tags: bug, localization, broken-link, international-sites

In the questions on enSO there is a block (shown only to users with an `Accept-Language` header for a given language), which suggests one to find an answer on a localized site.

I see this block in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53984400/1991579).

> [image]

The text is about ruSO, but the link leads to jaSO: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?utm=soenseru&fromen=337bc90019ee2.

Comment: Is this still an issue today?